# How to generate Cloudfront signed url for sse kms encrypted files using boto3?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-cloudfront, boto3

How can I generate a signed url for Cloudfront for sse kms encrypted files using boto3?  I'm using a custom domain so that https can be used.

```
<Error>
<Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
<Message>
Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed keys require AWS Signature Version 4.
</Message>
<ArgumentName>Authorization</ArgumentName>
<ArgumentValue>null</ArgumentValue>
<RequestId>063D9D2F5214E53A</RequestId>
<HostId>
jVazJY0g4jSDZSKB1iYHzFz7CWGlulU3eBEmg1E2OilYURzrdKGQI0xDVCWalQWtdNYSGz/5+DM=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

The code below is what I was using for creating signed urls prior to using sse kms but the signed urls generated now give this error:

```
    def rsa_signer(message):
        private_key = open('./pk-APKAJPF6OMQQZWEXQPUA.pem', 'r').read()
        return rsa.sign(
            message,
            rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(private_key.encode('utf8')),
            'SHA-1')  # CloudFront requires SHA-1 hash

    key_id = 'APKAJPF6OMQQZWEXQPUA'
    cf_signer = CloudFrontSigner(key_id, rsa_signer)

    expires = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)
    signed_url = cf_signer.generate_presigned_url(
        url,
        date_less_than=expires)
    # ExpiresIn=100
    return signed_url
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether this is possible with a CloudFront pre-signed URL, at least natively.  The CloudFront origin access identity creates a second signed URL (or something equivalent) behind the scenes...

> CloudFront typically uses signature version 2 for authentication when it requests objects in your Amazon S3 bucket.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html#private-content-origin-access-identity-signature-version-4

I'd have to test to be sure,  but I suspect there may not be a native solution.

Modifying the request in-flight using a Lambda@Edge Origin Request trigger to generate a V4 signature and inject it might be a viable workaround, and indeed might be the *only* workaround.

It's also possible that if the objects were in a bucket in a region that only supports Signature Version 4, CloudFront might do the right thing, authmatically, since it does work correctly with S3 in those regions.

Comment: Hi Michael.  I'm wondering if somehow there is a way to get my code to do a sigV4 signing.  I just can't get my head around where/how I'd do that...

Comment: @DukeDougal the issue isn't what *your* code is doing.  CloudFront's Origin Access Identity creates a *new* signature on the back-side to send to S3 (invisible to you) and this is where things start to break down -- CloudFront OAI uses V2 if the bucket supports it, yet in order for S3 to interact with KMS, the incoming request must be V4.  If you take a look at the [S3 regions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region) and find one that supports Signature V4 **only**, your simplest solution if you need KMS keys will be to try this with a bucket in one of those regions.